# Historical flight path data

Tags: data-request, government

Im looking for open data on historical US flight paths. I know the FAA has a real-time data stream that gives the flight, latitude, longitude, and altitude of planes. I want this data for the past 10 years. Anyone know if this is available?

Comment: I'd try and post it on ESRI GeoNet to see if you get more respond than here. https://geonet.esri.com/welcome

Comment: Does Flightradar24 keep historical records?

Comment: https://www.flightradar24.com/faq -- Only 7 days of historical records for free and 30 for paid subscribers.

Comment: This kind of data is highly valued by airline companies as it provides insight in competitors' activities, so I doubt you'll be able to get it for free.

Answer (score 2):

You can data till 2002 here.

https://www.datazar.com/hub/Airline/data

Full Disclosure - I work for datazar, an open source data library where people can discover, work with and share data.

Comment: great, thank you for this link! Do you guys provide US - related flight data only?

Answer (score 1):

Check out [openflights](http://openflights.org/) - might be useful?